# React Native - using ref in functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In my React Native app, I'm using the library, `react-native-card-flip`.

In the class component, I use it as follows:

```
<CardFlip style={styles.cardContainer} ref={(card) => this.card = card} >
  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.card} onPress={() => this.card.jiggle({ count: 2, duration: 100, progress: 0.05 })} ><Text>AB</Text></TouchableOpacity>
  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.card} onPress={() => this.card.flip()} ><Text>CD</Text></TouchableOpacity>
</CardFlip>
```

However, if I put the same thing in a functional component, I get an error about the 'ref'.

```
Undefined is not an object. Evaluating _this.card = card.
```

Something wrong with `ref` in the functional component. How can I correct this? Can you please help?

Comment: you have to use `useRef` https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

Comment: I tried this. The error goes away, but the CardFlip component just doesn't render.

Comment: I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use the `ref` in the functional component, you have to:

1. Create a ref using `useRef`;

`const card = useRef(null);`

2. Assign this ref to the cardFlip

`CardFlip ref={card}`

3. Do actions on it using the `current` property of the `ref`.

`card.current.jiggle(...)`.

Depending on how you've configured your `CardFlip`, (if the `jiggle` and `flip` are functions and `CardFlip` is a functional component) you may need to use `forwardRef` and `useImperativeHandle`. Try out this answer as is, if it doesn't work then I'll modify the answer.

Comment: I've tried it in exactly the same way. It doesn't work. The component CardFlip is coming from this library - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-card-flip

Comment: Can you log `card.current`? Which methods does it provide?